# Two level reordering of view in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to create a view in which there are two levels first level is goal and second level is task. A user can reorder the goal or a user can reorder the task within his parents(Goal). please suggest what would be best approach. I am using collection view controller but it is useful for only one level. problem is that goal or task can be dynamic in size[image]

Comment: I'd go with a `UITableView`, not a `UICollectionView`. But your question is too broad.

Comment: have you got my problem? I can easily reorder if there is no hierarchy but I have to handle hierarchy with dynamic height(might be parent or child)